# Mac OS X how to change where an app looks for libraries

Tags: macos, qt, package

I'm building an application using Qt5.1.1 on a Mac. I'm using packages to create an installer. I have it set up so that the installer installs the .app file and all of the libraries into a folder in /Applications/. The problem is when I install the application it is not looking where I want it to look for the libraries.

An otool -L shows this:

```
esu:
    libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /Users/ken/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /Users/ken/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /Users/ken/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /Users/ken/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtSerialPort.framework/Versions/5/QtSerialPort (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.1.0)
    /Users/ken/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

How can I change where the application is looking for these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `macdeployqt` it will change some of them automaticaly (thoses used by Qt) for the other ones, you can do it with `install_name_tool`

```
install_name_tool -change oldpath  newpath target
```

Comment: So the install_name_tool command might look something like: install_name_tool -change /Users/ken/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets ../../../QtWidgets ?

Comment: @JaredPrice I forgot the target, your `../../../QtWidgets` depend from where you type the command line...

Comment: @JaredPrice then you can validate the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going to where my release esu.app file was and I just used the macdeployqt. Trying to manually set up lib dependencies with install_name_tool was too much of a pain.

This is the command I used:

```
macdeployqt esu.app -verbose=2 -dmg
```

Comment: Be aware, sometimes `macdeployqt` is not enough